# remember input fields

Tags: php

I have a code like this in my register form

```
$_POST['email'] = trim($_POST['email']);
        if($_POST['email']){
             if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-])*\.[a-z]{2,4}$", $_POST['email'])){
              $error['emailerror'] = "  <span class='Register_Tip'>Wrong Email</span>";
```

it tell the user that the email is wrong

but after he see the error the form is reset

i need the form to remember the value that the user wrote

Comment: paste some html form code as well.

Comment: Why not just add a value in your form for the email field? You can populate it with `$_POST['email']` if it's already set. Also, `eregi` is deprecated - you shouldn't be using it for production code any more.

Comment: @GBD i used a code before javascript i think when i refresh the page value dont reset thats what iam searching for

Comment: @andrewsi iam sorry this is old code and iams still learning if u can advice me what should i use instead of eregi

Comment: @Zeroic - try using `preg_match` instead.

Comment: Using an email syntax checker is not judicious. Actually, an email address can take any syntax. For example, your regex is looking for LETTERS after the last ".", but addresses with .<number> exists. (see this example : http://wiki.42registry.org/page/Resolve)

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks so much iam gonna change my code

Comment: @Neozaru Thanks for your info iam gonna check it and change my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to check either the POST data of the corresponding input is exist or not like below:

```
<input type='text' name='email' value ="<?php isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : '' ?>" >
```

Comment: thanks i found this code
<script language='javascript'>
function tools(code) {
document.vbform.message.value += ' ' + code + ' ';
document.vbform.message.focus();
}
</script>
when i refresh the page the value does not reset but the register form i use post data and return with error so iam gonna check your code thanks